# Async inside Using block

Tags: c#, async-await, using

I have the following async function in C#:

```
private async Task<T> CallDatabaseAsync<T>(Func<SqlConnection, Task<T>> execAsync)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        return await execAsync(connection);
    }
}
```

It allows to execute any async function **execAsync** that takes SQL connection as an argument and uses it to make a database call, by providing the connection object and ensuring it would be properly closed.

This function is then called from an action in a WebApi controller, as follows:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MyAction()
{
    Func<SqlConnection, Task<SomeType>> execAsync = (function definition here);
    await CallDatabaseAsync(execAsync);
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

This all works great until I make one change to the WebApi action: I remove async/await from it. I do not want to wait for the database call because I do not care about the result, I just want to fire and forget.

This still seems to work fine - i.e. if I navigate to the action's URL in the browser I do not get any errors. But actually there is a problem - the database connection does not get closed. After 100 calls to the action, connection pool reaches its default limit of a 100, and the application stops working.

What am I doing wrong? What do I need to change in **CallDatabaseAsync()** so that it absolutely ensures that the connection would be closed, no matter what?

Comment: Are you sure it's that connection that it's not being closed?

Comment: @PauloMorgado Pretty sure. All database calls go via **CallDatabaseAsync()**, and this particular controller action invokes **CallDatabaseAsync()** only once.

Comment: Could you show an example async func you pass to this generic executor?

Comment: @WiktorZychla, **Func<SqlConnection, Task<SomeType>> execAsync** is passed as a lambda expression like this:

Comment: @WiktorZychla, **Func<SqlConnection, Task<SomeType>> execAsync** is passed as a lambda expression like this:

connection =>
connection.QueryAsync<SomeType>(storedProcName, param, null, commandTimeoutSeconds, CommandType.StoredProcedure)

where **QueryAsync<T>()** is an extension method on SqlConnection defined in Dapper.

Comment: Try wrapping that code in a **try/finally** block and add some logging or set a breakpoint to see if it ever gets there.

Comment: @PauloMorgado Tried try/finally - breakpoint in the finally block never gets hit. This explains why the connection never gets closed, but why the finally block never executes is not clear.

Comment: @Andrew, try also to add some logging to it.

Comment: @PauloMorgado I changed the body of the **using** block as follows:  

T result;  
connection.Open();  
File.AppendAllText(@"C:\q.txt","1");  
result = await execAsync(connection);  
File.AppendAllText(@"C:\q.txt", "2");  
return result;  

The outcome is: on first call after the website starts, both 1 and 2 get logged. On all subsequent calls, only 1 gets logged.

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheMagicOfUsingAsynchronousMethodsInASPNET45PlusAnImportantGotcha.aspx

Comment: Can you show how your action method looks like after you remove `async` and `await`?

Comment: Can you show `execAsync`?

Comment: `I do not want to wait for the database call because I do not care about the result, I just want to fire and forget.` - This is almost certainly wrong. Are you aware that "fire and forget" on ASP.NET actually means "I don't care if this code actually runs"?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In ASP.NET, each request has a special [SynchronizationContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx). This synchronization context makes the code that runs after the `await` use the same "context" of the original request. For example, if the code after the `await` accesses the current [HttpContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext(v=vs.110).aspx), it will access the `HttpContext` that belongs to the same ASP.NET request.

When a request terminates, the synchronization context of that request dies with it. Now, when the asynchronous database access completes, it tries to use the `SynchronizationContext` that it captured before the `await` to run the code after the `await` (which includes the code that disposes of the SQL connection), but it cannot find it anymore because the request has terminated.

What you can do in this case is make the code after the await not depend on the current ASP.NET request's `SynchronizationContext`, but instead run on a Thread-pool thread. You can do this via the [ConfigureAwait](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait(v=vs.110).aspx) method like this:

```
private async Task<T> CallDatabaseAsync<T>(Func<SqlConnection, Task<T>> execAsync)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        return await execAsync(connection).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Yacoub. One of my colleagues suggested the same thing to me, and explained exactly what you said in your answer. I tested it and it does work as expected, connections always get closed. Marking this as correct answer.