# ToListAsync throws Cannot access a disposed object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, async-await

Does any know why `ToListAsync` would throw an error:

> "System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object"

in the following code?

```
using (var c = new Context())
{
    var companies = await c.Database.SqlQuery<Company>("exec 
            GetStoredPrcedure @id", new SqlParameter("@id", id))
        .ToListAsync();

    // Process companies.
}
```

Here is the complete stack trace.

> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) 
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, 
>   Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataAssemblyHelper.
>   SafeLoadReferencedAssembly(AssemblyName assemblyName) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataAssemblyHelper.d__0.MoveNext() 
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable'1 source, Func'2 predicate) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.ImplicitLoadAssemblyForType(Type type, Assembly callingAssembly) 
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.TryDetermineCSpaceModelType(Type type, EdmType& modelEdmType) 
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ColumnMapFactory.CreateColumnMapFromReaderAndClrType(DbDataReader reader, Type type, MetadataWorkspace workspace) 
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.InternalTranslate[TElement](DbDataReader reader, String entitySetName, MergeOption mergeOption, Boolean streaming, EntitySet& entitySet, TypeUsage& edmType) 
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.d__73'1.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- 
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) 
>   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter'1.GetResult() at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.d__3d'1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() 
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.d__9'1.MoveNext() 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() 
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter'1.GetResult() 
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.d__70'1.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- 
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) 
>   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter'1.GetResult() at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyAsyncEnumerator'1.d__0.MoveNext() 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() 
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbAsyncEnumerableExtensions.d__5'1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() 
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Services.Companies.CompanyService.d__41.MoveNext() 
>   in API\src\Services\Companies\CompanyService.cs:line 927

The exception doesn't appear until the server experience increased traffic. I suspect the GC is disposing of the connection before the entire result set is returned but I'm not sure why or if there is anything I can do about it.

Comment: What code calls this code? Under what context does this run?

Comment: Not enough information, what lines throws, whats the stack trace (minimal) who calls this and how, i doubt there is a bug with GC or it cleans up anything that it shouldnt

Comment: The call is part of a web api. My guess is a variable holding the connection is going out of scope within Entity Framework. The exception then occurs if the GC is run before the ToListAsync returns.

Comment: Pertinent? https://stackoverflow.com/q/37357828/68432

Comment: The stacktrace has nothing to do with db connections.  It is failing trying to load assemblies (possibly for whatever assembly defines `Company` type).